# How to install "bought" softwares from the command line?

Tags: command-line, apt

I love doing things the command-line way and need to install some proprietary softwares that are available free of cost but have to be "bought" from the software center:

[image: screenshot]

How do I install such softwares from the command-line?

Answer (score -1):

Install package and assume yes to all queries

`sudo apt-get install *package_name* -y`

Comment: It is not a convenient method to download a software from any website and resolve its dependencies when it is available in the repositories.

Comment: Nopes, apt-get won't report a package by that name since it actually requires ppa repository to be added which is what the basic problem is, since I have not idea which ppa to add for such softwares.

Comment: I don't get this: Why should I install steam?

Comment: There are some software (like Minitube) for which you **have** to go through the Software Center. That will install a password-protected repository from which you can download the software.